# Getting Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type when using constructor to create objects

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store the records with sqlalchemy. This is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Numeric, ForeignKey, String, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Budgets(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budgets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Numeric(19, 4), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, userid, amount):
        self.userid = userid,
        self.amount = amount


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///budgetNew.db', echo=True)
#Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session()
budget1 = Budgets('123234', 300)
session.add(budget1)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

But I get error saying

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO budgets (userid, amount) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (('123234',), 300.0)]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am giving you a +1 for perfectly self-contained and concise code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of your constructor completely and change the Budgets creation call, it will work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Numeric, ForeignKey, String, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Budgets(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budgets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Numeric(19, 4), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///budgetNew.db', echo=True)
#Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session()
budget1 = Budgets(userid='123234', amount=300)
session.add(budget1)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

If you need the constructor overridden for some reason, you can do this:

```
class Budgets(Base):
    # [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Budgets, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.userid = args[0]
        self.amount = args[1]

# and then call
budget1 = Budgets('123234', 300)
```

But even in such a case, I would rather stick with only **kwargs and rather do this, because that follows the sqlalchemy habits:

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Budgets, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # whatever else is needed

# and then call
budget1 = Budgets(userid='123234', amount=300)
```